# Problem with mobile menu on Wordpress page - menu is not showing the links in the menu

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

Mobile menu suddenly stopped working on mobile.
I have the menu collapsing into a hamburger menu icon for mobile, but tapping on it does nothing on my phone and other people's phones. Yet it works when clicking on it on mobile simulators in Google Chrome DevTools and when shrinking the normal browser window.

[my webpage](https://digitalni.manever.si/)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a problem with your JavaScript being merged into a single file. I see you are delivering your HTML, CSS and JavaScript optimized. It is likely to be an issue with a single CSS or JavaScript file that conflicts with all the rearranging that the automatic optimization processes perform.

Try disabling JavaScript (or CSS) minification and combining in your LiteSpeed Cache for WordPress plugin, or any other plugin you use for HTML, CSS and JavaScript optimization. Than purge the whole cache and check if the menu works.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lscwp/ts-optimize/